# Ionic Package unable install

Tags: ionic-framework, package, installation

I have downloaded latest node version 4 and tried to install ionic.

But it was loading for long time in command prompt.

```
npm install ionic -g
```

Then I have downloaded 0.10.38 and it started downloading.

Whether ionic supported only in the 0.10 version.

While Installing with higher version getting below error

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "ionic" "-g"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6

npm ERR! Callback called more than once.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
C:\Users\<users>\AppData\Roaming\npm
└── (empty)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "ionic" "-g"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6

npm ERR! Callback called more than once.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
C:\Users\<users>\AppData\Roaming\npm
└── (empty)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "ionic" "-g"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6

npm ERR! Callback called more than once.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

Comment: seems like version of node is the problem . Try using 4.X.X

Comment: try to use older node version. Your are using version 5. I am using node version 4.4.7

Answer (score 4):

The error message says "`node v5.0.0`". Make sure you are using `Node 4` and `not 5`. Ionic doesn't yet work with `Node 5.x.x`. Use `node -v to` check for **version**.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to run npm uninstall -g ionic
then install new nodejs vesrion from the https://nodejs.org/en/download/
Once you have completed your latest nodejs installation.
Try to install ionic using 
npm install -g ionic
if you are using mac os or ubntu then you can use sudo npm install -g ionic.

Answer (score 2):

i think u should try this first node.js then commands 
`$ sudo npm install -g cordova` after it completes then install this 
`$ sudo npm install -g ionic` since i used sudo it may ask for password

check weather u done these steps

1. node.js
2. npm install -g cordova
3. npm install -g ionic
4. ionic --version //to check u have installed correctly
5. ionic start myapp blank //or tabs or sidemenu

now it will download all required files

check this link https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: Ionic not getting installed for node version 4.0.0 where its getting installed for the node 0.10.38 version. Whether ionic or cordova has any dependencies with node version.

Comment: Still facing 
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "ionic" "-g"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6

for node 5.0.0 version

Comment: I have formatted my OS and then installed latest version of node. Ionic got  installed. I think some problem with my previous install. Anyway thanks alot friends

Answer (score 2):

On Windows it may be a pain to get a working environment sometimes. To speed up Ops, you can try to use the **ionic-box** https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-box.

**Ionic-Box** is a ready-to-go development environment with Ionic, Cordova, and Android.

Answer (score 2):

Steps to install proper nodejs, cordova and ionic may help , try to follow mention below steps

1) Install compatible version of nodejs (windows)

2) Configured path of nodeJs from Computer property Advance environment variable.

3) check npm -v is working

4) run npm install -g cordova

5) if not started configured nodejs/npm to use http instead of https package using ssl false

6)run npm install -g ionic

Answer (score 2):

You can run the following command to downgrade the version :

`npm install npm@4.5.0 -g`
or 
`npm install npm@latest -g`

Answer (score 2):

You can use Yeoman generator to create your ionic project, which is very easy to use.

here you can find out more : 
http://yeoman.io/learning/index.html

to install yeoman :

```
npm install -g yo
```

Usage :
Make a new directory, and cd into it

```
mkdir my-ionic-project && cd $_
```

Run yo ionic, optionally passing an app name:

```
yo ionic [app-name]
```

more information :

https://github.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the below link, first you need to install cordova once successfully installed then install ionic.
Link - https://evothings.com/doc/build/cordova-install-windows.html

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have a some problem like this one check this I hope this help you.

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2477

Run this:

```
npm install --save-dev @ionic/app-scripts
```